# jstack alternative for linux redhat 6

Tags: linux

I am following the example given here to find thread stack 
http://code.nomad-labs.com/2010/11/18/identifying-which-java-thread-is-consuming-most-cpu/

unfotunately there is no jstack available on my redhat linux box. and according to this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html  jstack is no longer available.

what alternative command can i user the same set of information.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Oracle's Java, OpenJDK, or another implementation? Do you have the full JDK installed or just the JRE?

Comment: I am using Oracle's java. is it till available in Oracle's JDK?

Answer (score 4):

Jstack is still available. You need to have the JDK installed, not just the JRE.

You can get this information without jstack. Send SIQUIT to the java process; you can do this with `kill -3 <pid>`. The JVM will then print a thread dump to standard out.